# How to set horizontal space for tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

Below is item in `tabular`. Using `tabular` text gets out of the page.

[image]

In-order to get rid of this. I tried with `\\`. But doesn't help. It's not aligned.

[image]

Can anyone help me to get the below

[image]

Below is code used

```
\section{Technical Skills}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l >{\hspace{8pt}:\hspace{10pt}} l}
\textbf{IDE/Tools} & STS, Eclipse, WindowBuilder, NetBeans, Jasper Studio, iReport, \\ QBrowser, IBM Rational Rose \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width of the second column using a `p` column, so that it stays inside the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\section{Technical Skills}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ : }p{.75\textwidth}}
\textbf{IDE/Tools} & STS, Eclipse, WindowBuilder, NetBeans, Jasper Studio, iReport,  QBrowser, IBM Rational Rose
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the picture you can see the text margins in black.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the maximum of your page width, you could use an X-column of the package `tabularx` here. The only thing you have to do is to put the longest description text, `\textbf{IDE/Tools}:` in your case, into the `\settowidth` command.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % scalable version of your font (for microtype)
\usepackage{microtype} % better kerning in table cells
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for demo
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo

\begin{document}    
\section{Technical Skills}
\blindtext
\newlength{\myl}
\settowidth{\myl}{\textbf{Other stuff}:} % put your longest description text here (without trailing withspace)
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{@{}p{\myl}@{ } X@{}}
    \textbf{IDE/Tools}: & STS, Eclipse, WindowBuilder, NetBeans, Jasper Studio, iRe\-port, QBrows\-er, IBM Rational Rose \\
    \textbf{Other stuff}: & More other stuff \\
    \textbf{Long stuff}: & \blindtext \\
\end{tabularx} 
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]